# Functions whose integral on every great circle is zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two continuous real functions on the sphere $S^2$, with the following property:

> The integral of $f_i$ on any [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) of the sphere is 0.

Does there exist a point $x$ on the sphere on which $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0$?

Motivation: if this theorem is true, it implies the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) and several interesting generalizations of it.

Comment: Silly question, but is it obvious that such functions exist, that are not just identically zero?

Comment: I recently heard a talk where it was claimed (IIRC) that your integral condition implies that $f_1,f_2$ are odd. Together with the Borsuk Ulam theorem, this implies your claim.

Comment: @Chappers: Take arbitrary odd functions.